# Determine if event target is `TextInput`

Tags: react-native

I am attempting to create a work-arround for the double-tap [`<ScrollView>` issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4087) in my React-Native form.

One of the answers on that thread is very close, it uses the following code:

```
<ScrollView
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
    contentContainerStyle={styles.content}
    keyboardDismissMode='on-drag'
    keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true}>
    <View
      onStartShouldSetResponderCapture={(e) => {
        const focusField = TextInputState.currentlyFocusedField();

        if (focusField != null && e.nativeEvent.target != focusField){
          dismissKeyboard();
        }
      }}>
        ...
    </View>
</ScrollView>
```

This dismisses the keyboard if you didn't tap on the currently selected `TextInput`, I would like to change it to only dismiss the keyboard if `e.nativeEvent.target` is not a `TextInput` which avoids the close and re-opening of the keyboard when you tap on a different input. However, `e.nativeEvent.target` is a number.

**How do I get the node type from this handle?**

Thanks